What is the difference between dissociation and ionisation exactly and is ionisation in this case connected to ionisation as in "ionisation energy"?
What exactly is the difference between ionisation and dissociation and is it connected to with ionisation energy

Why is this question closed? It's not a homework question!!!

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure. // Generally, a question that is mere just a question, is a bad question on CH SE site.  A question, where the answer can be easily found by searching, is a bad question too.

Ionisation is a loss of one electron, producing also a positive ion. It may happen in an atom or in a group of different atoms, like in a molecule. Here are two examples of ionisations :
$$\ce{Na -> Na+ + e-}$$ $$\ce{H2O -> H2O+ + e-}$$Dissociation is not a loss of something. It is a spatial separation of a group of ions in two or many individual ions, one (or several) positive ion(s) and one (or several) negative ion(s). Dissociation cannot happen in an atom. It must happen in a substance made of at least two different atoms. Here are two examples of dissociations . $$\ce{NaCl -> Na+  +  Cl-}$$ $$\ce{Al2(SO4)3 ->  2 Al^{3+} + 3 SO4^{2-}}$$
